# И опять вводные слова в начале присоединительного оборота

Tags: пунктуация

Как бы вы расставили знаки препинания в этом предложении, учитывая, что вводное слово выделяется вместе со всем оборотом?

Такие сценарии характерны для оборудования с непосредственным подогревом, например, для колонных или теплообменных аппаратов, а также емкостей с наружным или внутренним обогревом, — например, при остановке перекачки обогреваемого продукта и особенно при одновременном закрытии входов и выходов защищаемой системы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Такие сценарии характерны для оборудования с непосредственным подогревом, **например для колонных или теплообменных аппаратов, а также емкостей с наружным или внутренним обогревом,** при остановке перекачки обогреваемого продукта и особенно при одновременном закрытии входов и выходов защищаемой системы.

(2) Такие сценарии характерны для оборудования с непосредственным подогревом, например для колонных или теплообменных аппаратов, а также емкостей с наружным или внутренним обогревом **(в частности, при остановке перекачки обогреваемого продукта и особенно при одновременном закрытии входов и выходов защищаемой системы).**

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Нежелательно использовать два  присоединительных оборота одинаковой структуры, непонятно, в чем заключается основное содержание, а что относится ко второму плану.